# Some moderator report columns are sorted alphanumerically when they should be numeric

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

In the [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/admin?filter=all) `Moderator Tools | history` grid, some columns (2-10 I think) can be sorted numerically.  But the last two seem to be sorted alphanumerically.  (I.e., 14, 218, 23,...)  Also, the problem only seems to be noticeable when using `filter=all`.  The other filters seem to work fine.  (Because of the data, I can't tell if `filter=day` is correct or not, but I would guess it's ok.)

I gather (from a conversation on the Teachers' Lounge) that not all sites have the problem.  It's also a very minor issue in the grand scheme of things.  Just an oddity.

Comment: Reproduced on Electrical Engineering (see TL post ID 4712275).  Due to the data, I can only reproduce it on the last column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix for this has been pushed and will take effect with our next build.